# Download file programmatically

Tags: forms, files

I have a custom module where I need to create a file and download it on form submission. So far, I managed to created the file and save it in public folder, but I cannot find a way to download it to client. This is the code I wrote so far.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $file_name = $date.'-event.ics';
  $cal_file = file_unmanaged_save_data('file content',"public://cal/$file_name",FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
  return new RedirectResponse(file_create_url("public://cal/211443-event.ics"));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can return a [BinaryFileResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21BinaryFileResponse.php/class/BinaryFileResponse/8.5.x) from a controller, or as 4k4 has added:

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse("public://cal/211443-event.ics");
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: This is what you want.

Comment: Yes, return it from a controller or set it directly in $form_state: `$form_state->setResponse($response);`

Comment: Nice. I didn’t know that. I’ll edit my post to include it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ll try it and I ll post the results here

Comment: You might be able to remove the call to file_create_url(). Let me know if that's the case and I'll update.

Comment: @Jaypan you were right. When I removed the file_create_url() the file downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 2):

That is what, for example, the [`Drupal\locale\Form\ExportForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21src%21Form%21ExportForm.php/class/ExportForm/8.8.x) class does. See the code used in [`ExportForm::submitForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21src%21Form%21ExportForm.php/function/ExportForm%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.8.x).

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($uri);
$response->setContentDisposition('attachment', $filename);
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

`$response->setContentDisposition()` sets the *Content-Disposition* header with the given filename. That is the filename used for the *Save file* dialog the browser will show to users.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very useful